# Gradient background CSS full height of the page

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have a website that uses a gradient like so:

```
#grad {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#87a0b4 80%, #6b88a1);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#87a0b4 80%, #6b88a1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#87a0b4 80%, #6b88a1);
    background: linear-gradient(#87a0b4 80%, #6b88a1);
}

<body id="grad">
```

The problem I am having is that if the page happens to stretch taller than my standard window (I'm sure this varies on different screens) the gradient resets.

The problem can be seen here:

http://overactiverexburg.com/Sage/bios.php

How can I fix this so the gradient always ends at the bottom regardless of how long the page ends up?

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the error instead of a link to your site.

Comment: The code I included is everything used for the gradient

Comment: The error is not reproduceable with just that code snippet, so you need to provide more code.

Comment: I added this <body id="grad">

Comment: Please look-up what reproduce means; if you have just the code you have provided then of course the code will work properly. The problem is that you haven't provided enough code for us to see this working in the context of your situation. In the future please provide at least minimal code required to exactly reproduce your error, preferably with a JSFiddle or similar link.

Comment: My man Diego was able to figure it out, thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your container class that now looks like this:

```
      .container {
         width: 980px;
        height: 1000px;
      }
```

for this

```
.container {
   width: 980px;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Just changing the height to fill the 100%

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `background-attachment: fixed` and `height: 100%` to your `#grad`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I added both lines and the result is the same

Comment: Please try and provide a bigger code sample, maybe try JSFiddle so we can work on it. When I'm editing in Firebug on your live site, I'm not able to reproduce the issue if I've applied my two CSS fixes.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
background-attachement: fixed;
```